# Getting variables outside of a javascript/HTML5 app

Tags: php, javascript, c++, html

How can I get the data stored in variables outside my window or tab of a foreign application? It is written in javascript and HTML5.Right now I have two ideas:

-Debbuging the browser as a plug-in.

-Scanning the browser memory

What would be easier? Is there another solution? Right now I am working with chrome and a facebook shooting game, and it would be a lot easier to do if the alternatives were done in js, php, or C++.

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds very strange to me. Maybe we could help you better when you would explain why you want to do that.

Comment: mostly this is not possible due to security limitations on the browsers.  You cant see what other pages the user has open.  If you were trying to open two windows, both of them yours, then you would need a server in between to pass variables around.

Comment: I have seen that that information is very protected in most web browsers, but I suppose it may be possible as a plug-in debugger(like firebug)

Comment: In what way are Chrome's development tool insufficient? You can set [breakpoints in your JS code](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts), print debug messages with `console.log`, and get the current values of variables by using the [JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console). What more functionality do you need to debug efficiently?

Comment: I dont want to debug the application just to show the data to the users, I want that information(shooting angle, position, wind, etc.) to draw the proyectile trajectory to help them.

Comment: Okay, for clarification: do you have control over (e.g. did you personally write/publish) the game in the browser and/or the native app you want to get the data? Or are you trying to get data out of a webpage you are not currently authoring? (It changes the problem significantly if you can't make changes to the code of either the web page or the native app.)

Comment: no, it is a totally foreign application written in javascript and HTML5. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Ever thought of using the **Node.js** server side to perform operations? You can create modules using C++ and connect it to part using Client-side libraries like **Socket.io** or other.

[NodeJS Website](http://nodejs.org/)

[NodeJS C++ Addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)

Comment: I edited the question to give a better explanation. The problem is to get the information stored in variables of foreign windows or tabs either from a web application or from a normal application, whatever is easier or faster.My first clues here are: Or i do a minidebug plugin for the web browser, or I scan the memory of the browser. Other ideas?

Comment: You can create an API like with a secret token. This API return a JSON format with all variables you want. You can do this?

Comment: the problem is that i dont have control over the other application, if adding an api to the app that gives me the information is what you meant.

Comment: Well, for this, I recommend Node.js and Socket.io

Comment: as far as I know, i need to have a serverside application to send me the variables from the site, and as I have said before, I dont have control over the other javascript application. Could you clarify me how could I get node.js and Socket.io to work with this conditions. And other question, is there a local way to do this? If javascript is clientside i suppose a browser plugin might do the work.